# When do you refrigerate your ginger beer?

Tags: carbonation, temperature, secondary-fermentation, ginger-beer

The standard instructions are: Make your bug; brew your sweet ginger 'tea'; cool; add bug to your tea, and bottle for second fermentation; let ferment, at room temperature, to your desired level, making sure to burp every day; refrigerate--drastically slowing, but not eliminating second fermentation.

The minor detail that I'm interested in, is that I've been burping them daily, and usually 3-5 days after I start getting audible gas, I burp them one last time, so that they don't burst, and then refrigerating them.  Should I not be burping them that last time?  Should I be leaving them under some pressure while they chill, so they can absorb it?

I'm wondering, because the fizz that I'm getting is decent, but pretty light.  I also think I'm leaving too much headspace, but one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the end product you are getting is nicely carbonated and you are not getting bottle bombs, and you like it then it sounds like you are doing it right.

I make my ginger beer far more like a fruit wine, but I have friends that follow a method very similar to the one you mentioned and their ginger beers are also very tasty.

If it works stick with it :)